# python get second value of a tuple in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, tuples

i have following list: `parent_child_list` with id-tuples:

```
[(960, 965), (960, 988), (359, 364), (359, 365), 
(361, 366), (361, 367), (361, 368), (361, 369), 
(360, 370), (360, 371), (360, 372), (360, 373), (361, 374)]
```

Example: i would like to print those values which are combined with the id 960. Those would be: 965, 988

I tried to convert the list into a dict:

```
rs = dict(parent_child_list)
```

Because now i could simply say:

```
print rs[960]
```

But unfortunately i forgot that dict cannot have double values so instead of getting 965, 988 as the answer i receive only 965.

Is there any easy option to keep the double values?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use defaultdict to create dictionary with list as its value type, then append values.

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [(960, 965), (960, 988), (359, 364), (359, 365), (361, 366), (361, 367), (361, 368), (361, 369), (360, 370), (360, 371), (360, 372), (360, 373), (361, 374)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in l:
    d[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to build a `list`, using `if` to filter out matching ids:

```
>>> parent_child_list = [(960, 965), (960, 988), (359, 364), (359, 365)]
>>> [child for parent, child in parent_child_list if parent == 960]
[965, 988]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always iterate:

```
parent_child_list = [(960, 965), (960, 988), (359, 364), (359, 365),
(361, 366), (361, 367), (361, 368), (361, 369),
(360, 370), (360, 371), (360, 372), (360, 373), (361, 374)]

for key, val in parent_child_list:
    if key == 960:
        print str(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension

```
[y for (x, y) in parent_child_list if x == 960]
```

will give you a list of y values for tuples whose x values equal 960.

Answer (score 0):

You have been given the way to extract individual using a list comprehension or loop but you can construct the dictionary you desire for all values:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for parent, child in parent_child_list:
...     d.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
>>> d[960]
[965, 988]
```

Alternative to using a raw python dict, you could use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` and just directly `append`, e.g. `d[parent].append(child)`